# Why this tutorial does not behave similarly in Win and iOS?

Tags: delphi

I was following [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Building_a_Basic_Media_Player) tutorial on the embarcadero docwiki and I noticed that when on iOS if I change the track bar the video will follow, or if I move another window above the video, when that window is removed I'll still be able to see the video. On windows though, changing the track bar position has no effect, and if another window comes above the media player then that window will be painted in it until I press play. Why does this happen?

Comment: Which Windows do you have and what codec is used in Video? FireMonkey application probably won't work corectly whn run on Windows XP. As for not being able to change the video position it is posible that this is the limitation of the codec that is used. I have seen this happen in some other Media Player application. For instance in old VLC when video was encoded using specific codec (I forgot which one was) you couldn't move back and forth in time or even pause the video. So I recomend you first try if this is happening with all video files to rule out the video codecs used.

Comment: I have the LAV video decoders, I will try others some others though and see if that works.

Comment: Since you decided to try other codecs I recomend you download genuine DivX and XVid codecs. Why? Becouse for theese I know they work OK since I'm using them and haven't expirienced such problems. The previous mentiond problem was due to VLC using its internal codecs instead of system ones.

Comment: I did try divX and Xvid but they were not recognised I think as the videos would not play inside of MediaPlayerControl. They do play using K-Lite codecs though. Unfortunately with K-Lite they have the behaviour I explained on my question. Oddly divX (and with it my program) works fine on iOS.

Comment: Have you removed other codec packs prior testing the DivX and XVid codecs. From my expirience most codec packs set themselves as top priority meaning that DivX and XVid aren't used even thou they are installed on the system.